# Check if user exist in LDAP before authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ldap, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I use ASP.NET Identity 2.0 and LDAP Authentication in an MVC project and my Loing method is as shown below. At the first step I check if the user is authenticated in LDAP, but I need to detect if there is no user in LDAP or the credentials are wrong so that return a correct message to the user. How can I do this?

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    ApplicationGroupManager groupManager = new ApplicationGroupManager();

    // Validate the user using LDAP 
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
        // FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);

        //code omitted for brevity

        if (this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
        {
            return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
            //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Issue");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong credentials");
        return this.View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't. That would be an information leak to an attacker. You don't want to tell him whether it was the username or the password that was wrong.

Comment: I not, how can I check if the user is an LDAP user? What about using **Membership.GetUser(model.UserName)** method before LDAP authentication?